# How to get all in and out time for an particular employee?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table is as below:

```
id       time_stamp                 Access Type    
1001    2017-09-05 09:35:00         IN
1002    2017-09-05 11:00:00         IN
1001    2017-09-05 12:00:00         OUT
1002    2017-09-05 12:25:00         OUT
1001    2017-09-05 13:00:00         IN
1002    2017-09-05 14:00:00         IN
1001    2017-09-05 17:00:00         OUT
1002   2017-09-05 18:00:00          OUT
```

I have tried this query below:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY A.emp_reader_id ASC
        ) AS SNo
    ,B.emp_code
    ,B.emp_name
    ,CASE 
        WHEN F.event_entry_name = 'IN'
            THEN A.DT
        END AS in_time
    ,CASE 
        WHEN F.event_entry_name = 'OUT'
            THEN A.DT
        END AS out_time
    ,cast(left(CONVERT(TIME, a.DT), 5) AS VARCHAR) AS 'time'
    ,isnull(B.areaname, 'OAE6080036073000006') AS areaname
    ,C.dept_name
    ,b.emp_reader_id
    ,isnull(c.dept_name, '') AS group_name
    ,CONVERT(CHAR(11), '2017/12/30', 103) AS StartDate
    ,CONVERT(CHAR(11), '2018/01/11', 103) AS ToDate
    ,0 AS emp_card_no
FROM dbo.trnevents AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.employee AS B ON A.emp_reader_id = B.emp_reader_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.departments AS C ON B.dept_id = C.dept_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DevicePersonnelarea AS E ON A.POINTID = E.areaid
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Event_entry AS F ON A.EVENTID = F.event_entry_id
ORDER BY A.emp_reader_id ASC
```

It works but it takes like below. Sometime have same in event and out event  :

```
SNo emp_code    emp_name    in_time                     out_time                    time    areaname    dept_name   emp_reader_id   group_name  StartDate   ToDate      emp_card_no
1   102         Ihsan Titi  NULL                        2017-12-30 12:16:26.000     12:16   Dubai       Sales       102             Sales       2017/12/30  2018/01/11  0
2   102         Ihsan Titi  NULL                        2017-12-30 12:16:27.000     12:16   Dubai       Sales       102             Sales       2017/12/30  2018/01/11  0
3   102         Ihsan Titi  2017-12-30 12:44:26.000     NULL                        12:44   Dubai       Sales       102             Sales       2017/12/30  2018/01/11  0
4   102         Ihsan Titi  2017-12-30 16:27:48.000     NULL                        16:27   Dubai       Sales       102             Sales       2017/12/30  2018/01/11  0
```

**Expected output:**

```
SNo emp_code    emp_name        in_time                     out_time                    time    areaname    dept_name   emp_reader_id   group_name  StartDate   ToDate      emp_card_no
1   102         Ihsan Titi      2017-12-30 12:16:26.000     2017-12-30 12:44:26.000     12:16   Dubai       Sales       102             Sales       2017/12/30  2018/01/11  0
2   102         Ihsan Titi      2017-12-30 12:50:26.000     2017-12-30 16:27:48.000     12:16   Dubai       Sales       102             Sales       2017/12/30  2018/01/11  0
```

kindly help i stuck here to get like this..

Comment: try to get all `access type IN` with order by `id       time_stamp` same with the `OUT` then join.

Comment: Wrap your query up in a derived table, then GROUP BY its result.

Comment: How clean is your data? Can you ***guarantee*** that every IN has a corresponding OUT, and vice versa? That's unlikely in my experience, so if there are extra IN or OUT records, how would you like to handle them?  (discard them? Assume an amount of working time? Or, better, don't use them in the calculation, but have extra fields to report how many there were?)

Comment: This is called a "gaps and islands" analysis - standard fayre in time and attendance systems. Beware the problem can become hard depending on the quality of the data and what assumptions can be made about working patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this :

```
select  A_In.emp_reader_id as empId,A_In.Belongs_to,A_In.DeviceSerialNumber,
        DT as EntryTime,
        (
         select min(DT) as OutTime
         from   trnevents A_Out
         where  EVENTID like 'IN'
         and    A_Out.emp_reader_id = A_In.emp_reader_id
         and    A_Out.DT > A_In.DT and DATEDIFF(day,A_In.Dt,A_Out.DT)=0
        ) as ExitTime from trnevents A_In   where    EVENTID like 'OUT'

    from    trnevents A_In
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I've approached it below is to say that if an event is the same type as the event before it then treat it as a "rogue".

Rogues always sit on their own, never paired with any other event.

All other events get paired such that `IN` is the first item and `OUT` is the second item.

Then I can group everything up to reduce pairs down to single rows.

```
WITH
  rogue_check
AS
(
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN LAG(F.event_entry_name) OVER (PARTITION BY A.emp_reader_number ORDER BY A.DT) = F.event_entry_name THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   AS is_rogue,
    *
  FROM
    trnevents     AS A
  LEFT JOIN
    EVent_entry   AS F
      ON  F.event_entry_id = A.event_id
),
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (                                         ORDER BY DT)   AS event_sequence_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_reader_number, is_rogue ORDER BY DT)   AS employee_checked_event_sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    rogue_check
)
SELECT
  MIN(event_sequence_id)                                    AS unique_id,
  emp_reader_number,
  MAX(CASE WHEN event_entry_name = 'IN'  THEN DT END)       AS time_in,
  MAX(CASE WHEN event_entry_name = 'OUT' THEN DT END)       AS time_out
FROM
  sorted
GROUP BY
  emp_reader_number,
  is_rogue,
  employee_checked_event_sequence_id - CASE WHEN is_rogue = 1 OR event_entry_name = 'IN' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
ORDER BY
  emp_reader_number,
  unique_id
;
```

Example Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE trnevents (
  emp_reader_number    INT,
  DT                   DATETIME,
  event_id             INT
);

CREATE TABLE Event_entry (
  event_entry_id       INT,
  event_entry_name     NVARCHAR(32)
);
```

Example Data:

```
INSERT INTO Event_entry VALUES (0, N'IN'), (1, N'OUT');

INSERT INTO trnevents VALUES
  (1, '2017-01-01 08:00', 0),
  (1, '2017-01-01 08:01', 0),
  (1, '2017-01-01 12:00', 1),
  (1, '2017-01-01 13:00', 0),
  (1, '2017-01-01 17:00', 1),
  (1, '2017-01-01 17:01', 1)
;
```

Example Results:

```
unique_id   emp_reader_number   time_in               time_out
1           1                   01/01/2017 08:00:00   01/01/2017 12:00:00
2           1                   01/01/2017 08:01:00   null
4           1                   01/01/2017 13:00:00   01/01/2017 17:00:00
6           1                   null                  01/01/2017 17:01:00
```

The `GROUP BY` turned out a bit more fiddly than I anticipated on the train and so may cause an expensive `SORT` in the execution plan for large data sets.  I'll also think about an alternative shortly.

Here is a demo with some simple dummy data demonstrating that it works for those cases at least.  *(Feel free to update it with other cases if they demonstrate any problems)*

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d06680d8ed374666760cdc67182aaacb

Comment: @BorislavAymaliev - Please show some decorum and some humility.  I commented on your answer to highlight two separate syntax errors that you had not spotted, this enabled you to correct them.  I also commented on a difference between your results and the description as I understand it from the OPs post and comments.  Based on what the OP said, the `IN` records ***do not*** cleanly map to the `OUT` records (`some time i get same time punch in/out`).  The answer you gave yields over-counting *(if I log in at 1pm and 2pm and out at 3pm, you say I worked for 3 hours?)*

Answer (score -2):

You can use a `PIVOT`

```
 select id, [in], out
 from
 ( select 
      id, time_stamp, accessType, 
     (ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by time_stamp) -1 )/ 2 rn   
   from yourtable ) src
 pivot 
 (min(time_stamp) for accessType in ([in],[out])) p
```

This assumes that each "in" is followed by an "out" and uses row_number to group those pairs of times.

Comment: The result will be same as i mentioned aboveSNo                  emp_reader_id       1                       0

1                    102                  2017-12-30 12:16:26.000 NULL
2                    102                 2017-12-30 12:16:27.000 NULL
3                    102                       NULL                    2017-12-30 12:44:26.000

Comment: @TimeAttendanceSystem No, it won't

Comment: i just used your code mentioned above exactly same and also try adding row number but result will same i mentioned

Comment: Re-worded this answer to use my example data, which demonstrates a few issues with this answer, as the OP stated that the INs and OUTs are not cleanly paired.  *(This answer is the final panel in the enclosed demo)*: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2a0e8fb536b49348b37d97767b5c444c

Comment: It may be implicit, but to be specific, this also assumes that each `out` is preceded by an `in`.  *(If the first record is an `out` the calculation `(rowid-1)/2` gives undesirable results.)*